# check uploaded file in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I need a snippet to check file for validity (I'm allowing users to upload xml files). So I need to check whether uploaded file is XML.
The best I can think of is just check if extension is ".xml". What if its replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try loading it like this and catch the exception:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, if they're uploading XML, then you're going to use it for something afterwards. In this case you should validate the XML against a Schema (XSD etc) so that you know you aren't going to hit unexpected values/layouts etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Urlmon.dll, there's a function called FindMimeFromData.

From the documentation

> MIME type detection, or "data
>   sniffing," refers to the process of
>   determining an appropriate MIME type
>   from binary data. The final result
>   depends on a combination of
>   server-supplied MIME type headers,
>   file extension, and/or the data
>   itself. Usually, only the first 256
>   bytes of data are significant.

So, read the first (up to) 256 bytes from the file and pass it to FindMimeFromData.

Answer (score 0):

If you must validate the xml (assuming you want to validate the entire thing) you can use the `XmlDocument` class and catch an exception if it's not XML.

Comment: Because it could be a hacker or malicious user searching for vulnerabilities, one might not want to reply on the file extension alone : )

Comment: Yeah, the only case where it might be OK to do a file extension check is when the application is just storing the file for the user as a service.. and not consuming it itself. Then checking the file extension would be an easy UI way to say "Hey, that's not an XML file." .. but it doesn't seem like that's the application here. Thanks for pointing that out.